# c++ Iterator crashing while iterating over vector

Tags: c++, boost, stl

I have a class **Iformat** which has virtual function operator() and each derived class implements this function.

```
class myClass
{
    std::vector<IFormat*> formatList_;
public:
  void formatAll()
  {
    foreach(IFormat* format , formatList_)
    {
        (*format)();
    }
  }

};
```

The `formatAll` function is called on an object of `myClass` and then in the loop, the `operator()` function is deleting this `myClass` object itself which invoked the `formatAll()` function which is leading to a crash as the iterators are getting corrupted.

**Constraints**: `operator()` definition can not be declared otherwise to return an error type.
Also , can not use some indicator variable to break out of loop.

Can somebody please suggest ways to handle the loop so that it does not crash by only changing the loop and iterators and following the constraints.
Thanks

Comment: I don't think we can solve this without more context. It looks like you've screwed up your memory management somewhere along the line, but you could have screwed it up anywhere. If the () operator of a format is deleting the parent then you clearly havn't defined the ownership very well...

Comment: The best thing to do is to duplicate the problem with a small example.  Extract just enough from the larger program to make a small example that you can post which demonstrates the problem.  Often you will find the issue yourself as you work on that.  if not, then you can post an example that others can compile and help you to debug.

Comment: Where is the [testcase](http://sscce.org) you're debugging with?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, sometimes with a complicated chain of operations stemming from callbacks, this problem can surface.

You have a few options:

1. copy the `formatList_` within `formatAll` and iterate over the copy; you're only copying pointers but this may still be undesirable if the container is large, or if you are running this in a tight loop somewhere;
2. in an event-driven framework, you can defer the execution of `(*format)()` until the start of the next application "tick", in this loop only adding it to some work queue; this is effectively the same as option #1, just a lot more complex, but if you *do* have such a framework it can slot in really nicely;
3. ensure, somehow, that the callback *cannot* modify the `formatList_`, directly or indirectly; you might achieve this by prohibiting "add" or "remove" options, or forcing *those* to be deferred.

The "cleanest" approach is option #3 but, again, unless you are in an event-driven framework it can be clumsy to implement.